# Saving a pandas dataframe using PyQt5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt5

I have created a simple window with two buttons and a table view in Qt designer and then save my ui as *user_interface.ui*. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4T9jB7Y99r91IUq9dqi6eVl5Hmj5qbR/view?usp=sharing) is the user_interface.

[image]

Then, I use the following code to generate some random data and display them on the window with the ***Generate data and display*** button click. I also have a save button to give the user the option to save the generated data as csv:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

from numpy.random import randn
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

ui,_=loadUiType('user_interface.ui')


class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.generate_table.clicked.connect(self.generate_data)

    def generate_data(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),index='A B C D E'.split(),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
        model = pandasModel(df)
        self.tableView.setModel(model)

        self.save_as_csv.clicked.connect(lambda: self.save_data_as_csv(df))

    def save_data_as_csv(self, df):
        name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', filter='*.csv')
        if(name[0] == ''):
            pass
        else:
            df.to_csv(name[0], index = False)

class pandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None


def main():
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.processEvents()
    window = MainApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I hit the ***Generate data and display*** button, it works fine and I see the generated table. If I keep hitting this button, I do see the random numbers change and it is what I want.

The problem is that when I want to save the generated data, If I have clicked the ***Generate data and display*** 20 times to change the data, I will be asked 20 times (except if I hit Cancel in the save popup window) and it basically is trying to save all the dataframes that have been generated on each click of the ***Generate data and display*** button. All I want to save is the most recent generated data right before I hit the ***Save as csv*** button. I can't figure out what I need to do to achieve that?

Comment: You're connecting the signal each time the generate button is clicked. Instead keep a reference to `df` that can be used in the save function, and only connect the signal in the constructor.

Comment: I see. Can you please be a little more specific about keeping a reference to `df`? Where in the code is the best place to define that reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because another instance of the signal is connected to `save_data_as_csv` each time `generate_data` is called. Instead declare the signal connection one time in the constructor and keep a pointer to the most recent dataframe in your class (`self.df`) so it no longer requires passing the dataframe as an argument.

```
class MainApp(QMainWindow, ui):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.generate_table.clicked.connect(self.generate_data)
        self.save_as_csv.clicked.connect(self.save_data_as_csv)

    def generate_data(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(randn(5,4),index='A B C D E'.split(),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
        model = pandasModel(self.df)
        self.tableView.setModel(model)

    def save_data_as_csv(self):
        name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', filter='*.csv')
        if(name[0] == ''):
            pass
        else:
            self.df.to_csv(name[0], index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. In my full code, I am actually using multiple save buttons to save different files in different tabs. I was trying to connect a single function to the different save buttons. But I think I need to use your approach and define different functions for different save buttons or use conditions inside this save function.